# Ionic button state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to replace ion-select options and implement the options in two buttons. Can somebody tell how this is done from the below code?

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label>{{ 'SELECT_LANGUAGE' | translate }}</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="languageSelected" (ionChange)='setLanguage()' [cancelText]="'CANCEL' | translate">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let item of languages" [value]="item.code">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Above is using select options and below generates two buttons but I want to be able to click each one to change the state.

```
<button ion-button large *ngFor="let item of languages" [value]="item.code">{{item.name}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you Thanks :-)

```
<div *ngFor="let item of languages">
<button ion-button large
    [value]="item.code">
        {{item.name}}
</button>
</div>
```